# css top attribute of adjacent divs

Tags: css

I have a div when clicked upon opens up another div. I want to change the position of my div #close-bar from top:0; to top:120px; but if I change that, the corresponding hidden div called #hiddenPanel maintains its original position.

I want the #hiddenPanel div to be adjacent to #close-bar when clicked upon, and all of its content to follow with it.
I have tried to play with the top properties of #hiddenPanel but haven't yet found out what wold make it work.
This is my jsfiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/gv6ffj0a/)

The code below is where I would want the #hiddenPanel to be positioned at:

```
#hiddenPanel {

    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    right:-200px; 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:grey; 
    height:150px;

}

#close-bar { 

    position:absolute; 
    left:-20px; 
    top:120px; 
    background:red; 
    color:white; 
    width:20px; 
    height:150px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display:block; 
    border-top-left-radius: 4em 3em; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4em 3em;

}
```

Thanks
-Sohail

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by exchanging top:120px on the div #hiddenPanel instead.